# Docker poetry installl returned a non-zero code (ChunkedEncodingError)

Tags: python-3.x, docker, python-poetry

I get an issue where when docker-compose up the dependency often fails to install and an error message appears like this:

[image]

This happens often, but sometimes it works.

**These are the tool that I used:**

1. docker version 20.10.5
2. docker-compose version 1.28.6

**Dockerfile :**

```
    FROM python:3.8-slim as python-base

# Setup ENV pyhton
ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PYTHONHASHSEED=random \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    POETRY_VERSION=1.1.4

# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install gcc musl-dev libffi-dev openssl make postgresql -y
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    curl \
    openssh-client \
    build-essential \
    openssh-client \
    libpq-dev python3-dev \
    python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-wheel \
    python3-cffi libcairo2 libpango-1.0-0 \
    libpangocairo-1.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
    libffi-dev shared-mime-info

# Copy all file
COPY . /src/debug-internal-tools

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /src/debug-internal-tools
ENV PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD}

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install
```

Comment: Looks like an network issue during install. Hard to debug ...

Comment: do you mean, this issue is because of my network?  @finswimmer

Comment: Yes, the error is telling something about "Connection broken" is is thrown by the `requests` package, which is used for getting information via the network (package metadata, the package itself, ...).

Comment: so what i need to do for handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are some packages in poetry that are not compatible with your python version `python3.8`. Try to change the python version at the first line of Dockerfile.
Also `RUN poetry update before poetry install`.